# Hide a link when clicked on

Tags: javascript, caching

I have a page that shows links with "x new comments". Then I click a link I want to hide that link. When I click the back button to come back to my page I want that link to still be hidden (I've now seen the comments so they are no longer new).

Can this be done with simple javascript? I don't want to reload the original page for performance reasons.

Comment: You'd need to keep a list of which links to show/hide in a cookie, then show/hide them based on that cookie anytime the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe this could helps.

Depends of the programming language you were using, you will need a session value.

For example, using jQuery and supposing you were using PHP:

```
<?php 
 //start the session
 session_start();

 //set the attribute
 $_SESSION['hide'] = false;

?>
<script>

//function to hide all class='test' elements
function hide(h){
 if(h){
  $('.test').hide();
 } else {
  $('.test').show();
 }
}

/*do this always when page loads
 * verify with the value stored in session to hide or not the links
 */
window.onload = hide(<?php echo $_SESSION['hide']; ?>);

//onready
$(function() {

 //when link class='test' is clicked
 $('.test').click(function(){

  //fadeOut or just $(this).hide();
  $(this).fadeOut();

  //set the session to hide = true
  <?php $_SESSION['hide'] = true; ?>

 });

});
</script>

//here goes your html
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Link" class="test">I am link 1</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Link" class="test">I am link 2</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Link" class="test">I am link 3</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Link" class="test">I am link 4</a>
</body>
```

Hope my idea works for you.

Answer (score 2):

To hide a link when clicked is simple:

```
var a = document.getElementById("yourA");
a.onclick = function(){
    this.style.display = "none";
    return false;
};
```

To keep it hidden for the next page load will require a tad more work.  You'll need to create a cookie after hiding the link, and read the same cookie whenever the page is subsequently loaded (and hide accordingly).

Comment: thanks. Wouldn't the bfcache preserve the javascript states when you navigate back to the page?

Answer (score 0):

This can definitely be done with basic JavaScript.

In general, here are the steps involved:

- register 'click' event handler on DOM element using a pre-written callback
- a click will now your callback and pass it an event object (we'll call it `e`)
- you can then hide the element based on the `e.target` attribute of the event object.